# Access VBA: Passing Form/Subform name to a Function?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to pass a form/subform name to a function without success.  The function steps thru each .Control on the subform and performs a simple set of look-ups & actions.  My code works as expected with the Form/Subform name hard coded; I am looking for a more generic approach.

Getting a type mismatch error on the function call, with and without quotes.

Example:

```
'Function Call
  call AuditChanges("forms![someForm]![someSubForm]")

'Audit Function
Sub AuditChanges(thisForm as form)
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim strTest as string

    For each ctl in thisForm.controls
        strTest = ctl.Value
        'do some stuff
    Next ctl

end sub
```

Any suggestions for proper syntax to pass the form/subform info?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Getting a type mismatch error on the function call"_ It's generally best to quote it in full, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sub call is all kinds of weird:

The likely cause of your error is the quotes. You're currently passing a string to your function containing `"forms![someForm]![someSubForm]"`

Furthermore, you shouldn't use parentheses when you're not receiving a return value (so never when calling a sub).

Also, the `Call` keyword has been deprecated a long time ago.

And you likely want to pass the form object, and not the subform control object

Try calling your sub like this:

```
AuditChanges forms![someForm]![someSubForm].Form
```

(Never had this many comments on one line of code before)

Comment: Sorry, the example was a weak attempt to illustrate my intent without cluttering detail.  :)

Comment: Erik, your suggestion "AuditChanges forms![someForm]![someSubForm].Form" (without quotes) works as desired.  - thank you

Comment: Good. I sometimes am a bit critical, about half my points (`call`, parentheses) are probably not the cause of any errors. A minimal example is often hard, the devil's in the details :)